# Why I shouldn't keep client_secret in mobile app in OAuth 2.0 (authorization code grant flow)

Tags: security, mobile, oauth-2.0

We've got an app, which should use authentification through 3-rd party OAuth 2.0 server, which acts as an authorization server.

As i understand there are two possibilities.

The "right" one is:

1. Mobile app stores client_id
2. Mobile app starts with GET /auth to receive authorization_code
3. Authorization server returns response with redirect to redirect_uri
   and attached authorization code. We assume, that redirect_uri is an
   endpoint on our own server.
4. Mobile app follows redirect
5. Our server receives request, takes authorization_code from query and
   exchanges it for access_token using POST /token method and
   client_secret (stored on server).
6. Server responses to mobile app with access_token
7. Mobile app takes access_token and uses it in future requests.

The "bad" one is:

1. Mobile app stores client_id **and client_secret**
2. Mobile app starts with GET /auth to receive authorization_code
3. Authorization server returns response with redirect to redirect_uri
   and attached authorization code. We assume, that application
   intercept it and takes authorization_code (we can simply ask to
   redirect to localhost).
4. Mobile app exchanges it for access_token using POST /token method
   and client_secret.
5. Mobile app takes access_token and uses it in all future requests.

So i can't see real difference between this two alternatives. In both cases we end up with access token. In both cases we need real user to enter his login and password in rather secure webview.

Even if some bad guys will distribute fake application... what do prohibit them from using our server's callback to exchange authorisation code for access_token? Our server can't distinguish "bad" and "good" application - it just receives request GET \callback?code=blablabla and replies with access_token.

So why should we keep secret on server? What is the case of fraud with faked applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With OAuth you have different flows that you can use according to your needs/setup. Depending of the different flows, the OAuth roles will also behave differently.

From your description I was not entirely sure what will take on the role of the Client. But the options are:

1. Backend server is the client
2. Mobile app is the client

For case 1, you don't need to store client ID or client secret on your app, as it will be your own backend server to communicate with the Authorisation Server and the Resource Server. If that is the case, then you can follow the Authorisation Code flow.

For case 2, it will be the app itself that communicates with Authorisation and Resource Server. In this case, the Implicit Flow is the recommended one. It is not considered a safe flow, and mobile devices or webapps are not considered a safe place to store the client secret, as you would have to store them in your app's code, somehow.
A (bit convoluted) scenario to explain why this isn't safe is the following: The client secret is issued by the Authorisation Server, or Service Registry, and any hack would require you to change it, which might mean changing the code. And in the case of a mobile app this would mean your users updating to a new version.
What seems to be widely suggested as an extra step of security (instead of the client secret) is to use the 'state' or 'nonce' fields to ensure that authorisation requests came from the same app to which the token was issued to.
From the RFC section 4.1.1 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.1):

> state
>
> ```
>      RECOMMENDED.  An opaque value used by the client to maintain
>      state between the request and callback.  The authorization
>      server includes this value when redirecting the user-agent back
>      to the client.  The parameter SHOULD be used for preventing
>      cross-site request forgery as described in Section 10.12.
> ```

The value to be passed in the state field is up to whoever makes the request. You can generate a random (or pseudo-random) number. The reply that the Authorisation Server sends back will have the state field filled exactly the way it was sent by the Client. You can then match the state field you received with the one you sent to see if they match.

Another step you can take is to have the Client send the redirect URI with the token request. This is useful so that the Authorisation Server can validate if the redirect URI in the request matches the one it has associated with the client ID. If you're using a 3rd party Authorisation Server you should check if it has this behaviour.

As a final security recommendation, **always use with HTTPS when communicating with the Authorisation Server or the Resource Server**.

This post explains well the different flows of OAuth: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2

Comment: That's right. Exactly the second case. And yes, as i understand, some 'state' field can make it safe. However it's not so obvious what i should use as 'state' field with mobile apps. One thing which can distinguish real app from fake app is certificate's data used for signing an app. Another way is crypto-magic between app and server. I didn't find full answer for this question and it's still unclear for me. Pity that nor google, neither apple didn't provide some way for provisioning unique (per installation) keys based on developer's secret key.

Comment: I see. I will elaborate on the use of the state field in my answer. Also, please note that this is only for the authentication step. The communication with the Resource Server is done with the use of the token alone. You are, of course, free to add your own extra security steps there.

Answer (score 1):

```
We assume, that redirect_uri is an endpoint on our own server.
```

I believe you are mixing up the role of your client and resource server here. Your
resource server (the server hosting your API) should of course never return the token to the mobile app (client) as it needs that token to authenticate the client in the first place.

In OAuth2, the client should acquire a token from the authorization server before communicating with the resource server.

It can use either the [implicit grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.2) or the [authorization code grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.1). In the latter case, it should use the grant without providing a client secret as mobile clients are considered public clients that cannot store secrets securely.

Comment: Well, suppose that we can obtain access_token on our server. Now step 5 is:
My backend receives request on the endpoint and asks authorization server to exchange attached auth code for access token. My backend stores access token and DOESN'T return it back to the mobile app. It will use it in a future to request Resource server (which is the same as auth server).

The question is the same: how can my backend link concrete user in application with concrete obtained access token in requests and verify that it's not from fake app? It's obvious in web apps due sessions... but not in mobile apps.

Comment: You are now talking about a backend server AND a resource server. When your mobile app is the client, you use OAuth2 to acquire a token that allows you to talk to a resource server. There is no separate backend server. If there was, you'd need a token to talk to it.