# Passing client secret to users in Github api

Tags: github-api

The [Github API docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/#oauth2-keysecret) state regarding OAuth2 Key/Secret:

> This should only be used in server to server scenarios. Don't leak your OAuth application's client secret to your users.

I want to understand what security risks does this pose, since I've seen a couple of web applications use front-end side scripting to query the APIs and passing the client id and client secret to take advantage of extra rate limits.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in "[What's the benefit of the client secret in OAuth2?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/14013)":

> An app requesting an access token has to know the **[client secret](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2#client-id-and-client-secret)** in order to gain the token. This prevents malicious apps that have not been authorized from using the tokens from ever obtaining a valid access token. It doesn't state anything about authenticating a user, but it's instead for authorizing an app to request access tokens.
>
> Web apps use client secrets because they represent huge attack vectors.
>   Let us say that someone poisons a DNS entry and sets up a rogue app "lookalike", the juxtapose might not be noticed for months, with this intermediary sucking up tons of data. Client secrets are supposed to mitigate this attack vector.
>
> Client secrets aren't used in other types of flows, because of the [sensitive nature of the client secrets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34749348/6309).
>   For example, you must not use them in JavaScript or desktop applications, both of which can be decompiled, examined, source code viewed, debugged, etc. **Servers are theoretically safe from prying, so the client secret is less vulnerable than it is on a desktop app**

Comment: Pragmatically speaking, your answer doesn't pinpoint to the security vulnerabilities simple front end requesting poses; assuming the OAauth application has no authorized users with sensitive data, only public read only access.